# How do I write a function for psql (Postgres) that will match the return value of gettimeofday() in C?

Tags: postgresql, debian

I have a pair of programs that need to utilize a common timestamp while running.  One program will be writing to Postgres tables with column type `timestamp without time zone` using `now()`.  The other program will be writing to binary files using values returned from the `gettimeofday()` C function.

We are targeting two versions of Debian/Postgres.  The first is Wheezy and Postgres 9.1.  For quite some time we used the following functions to get common values:

**C (compiled to program `gettimeofday`)**

```
struct timeval tv;
memset(&tv, 0, sizeof(tv));

gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

unsigned long val = tv.tv_sec * 1000000;
val += tv.tv_usec;
val /= 1000000;

printf("%lu\n", val);
```

**psql**

```
CREATE FUNCTION ms_ts(ts timestamp without time zone) RETURNS bigint
    LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT
    AS $_$select cast(round(1000 * extract('epoch' from $1)) as bigint);$_$;
```

This returned a common value that we could use.  We aren't concerned with time zones--just about getting a common value between the two programs.  When we moved to Debian Jessie and Postgres 9.4, it appears the behavior of this psql `extract()` function changed.

**Machine 1, Debian Wheezy, Postgres 9.1, psql 9.1.20**

```
date: Tue Mar  8 09:06:30 CST 2016
hwclock: Tue 08 Mar 2016 09:15:11 AM CST  -0.375327 seconds
select now() -> 2016-03-08 09:07:23.183816-06
select extract('epoch' from cast('2016-03-08 09:00:08.277701' as timestamp without time zone));
-> 1457449208.2777
```

**Machine 2, Debian Jessie, Postgres 9.4, psql 9.4.6**

```
date: Tue Mar  8 09:06:31 CST 2016
hwclock: Tue 08 Mar 2016 09:15:12 AM CST  -0.890904 seconds
select now() -> 2016-03-08 09:07:23.60542-06
select extract('epoch' from cast('2016-03-08 09:00:08.277701' as timestamp without time zone));
-> 1457427608.2777
```

So I researched and found that `extract()` has an option `at time zone [...]` to pick what time zone to extract the epoch with.  Using `'uct'` as the time zone seems to fix the issue on Jessie/Postgres 9.4, but it then messes up Wheezy/Postgres 9.1.

**Machine 1, Debian Wheezy, Postgres 9.1, psql 9.1.20 (Values are off by six hours, likely based on local time zone CST)**

```
select extract('epoch' from now() at time zone 'uct'); -> 1457579365
./gettimeofday -> 1457557765
```

**Machine 2, Debian Jessie, Postgres 9.4, psql 9.4.6 (values match)**

```
select extract('epoch' from now() at time zone 'uct'); -> 1457558544.44372
./gettimeofday -> 1457558543
```

What is the appropriate way to use `extract()` to match `gettimeofday()`?  Or has the implementation just changed in such a way that I'll need two versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is apparently just a behavior change of the `extract()` function.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/release-9-2.html

> Make EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timestamp without time zone) measure the epoch
>   from local midnight, not UTC midnight (Tom Lane)
>
> This change reverts an ill-considered change made in release 7.3.
>   Measuring from UTC midnight was inconsistent because it made the
>   result dependent on the timezone setting, which computations for
>   timestamp without time zone should not be. The previous behavior
>   remains available by casting the input value to timestamp with time
>   zone.

So this implementation will work across platforms:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ms_ts(ts timestamp without time zone) RETURNS bigint
    LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT
    AS $_$select cast(round(1000 * extract('epoch' from $1::timestamptz)) as bigint);$_$;
```

I don't really care whether the result factors in time zone or not, just that it behaves the same as `gettimeofday()`.

Addendum: Another factor is the internal timezone that Postgres is set to.  This can be viewed by using:

```
show timezone;
```

If it's not 'localtime' then the value won't match gettimeofday().  To set to localtime for a given user use:

```
alter user yourusername set timezone='localtime';
```

Answer (score 0):

The "epoch" is the count of seconds since a fixed point. Traditionally on unix-based systems this is 1st January 1970, midnight at UTC.

Naturally if you change your timezone then it changes the difference from that fixed point. To be honest, I'm not sure the idea of measuring time since epoch without a timezone makes much sense. Actually, I've never really found the whole "timestamp without time zone" thing much use.

So - always provide a timezone if you want an absolute point in time (like you do in this case).

```
richardh=> SELECT extract(epoch from '1970-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamptz);
 date_part 
-----------
         0
(1 row)

richardh=> SELECT extract(epoch from '1970-01-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamptz);
 date_part 
-----------
     -3600
(1 row)
```

Comment: But the time zone seems to be the same on both servers as the output of `now()` suggests. Plus: the actual  test query uses a fixed date without a time zone.

Comment: I'm gonna revise the question a bit to compare it with the output of the gettimeofday function in C.  Which ultimately is what I need to do.